# Business Unit Data model in Contact builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit, data-designer

In the my BU I don't having access to DE syncronized,  so my
Corporate created me filtered and shared DEs in the shared DE folder.
How do I build the data model in Contact and set up the different relationships of the Sales cloud objects?

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have access to synchronised DE it means the connector is setup at the master level.

In order to maintain the DE shared with your BUs, they will need to build automation at the parent BU level, to ensure these shared DE are populated as replica of the synchronised DE.

To setup your data model you need to have an understanding of how these objects speak together in CRM and reflect it in SFMC.
I would suggest to ask them a screenshot of the current data model at the parent BU level.

Let's say you have a synchronised DE for:
Contact
Account
Custom object 1

In contact builder, data designer, create a new attribute group: let's call it Master Data Extensions.

Step 1 will be to link your contact to the contact table.
Link it via your unique ID (assuming it's a DE sync clone of contact object this will be done using Contact ID)

Step 2 proceed to link Account to contact using PersonContactId on the account object matching to contact id

Step 3 any custom object, you need to have an ID on the object that you can link to contact (so the contact id)

Remember you also need to set a relationship between the DE. Contact to Contact should normally be 1-1. Custom object might have a 1 to many (1 contact - many custom objects).